# jssh telnet fails even after installing the add-on on Linux

Tags: ruby, rubygems, firewatir

I am working with ruby gem "firewatir (1.6.5)" and mozilla
    Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.1.9) Gecko/20100330 Fedora/3.5.9-1.fc11   Firefox/3.5.9.<\i>

I have installed the jssh.*.xpi extension for mozilla 3.5 for Linux and it works for sometime.

But the problem is that after running some scripts I get the error that "failed to telnet to localhost at port 9997".After this, sometimes re-installing the extension works, but sometimes it does not.

Is there any other way of ensuring that the jssh extension works?

Thanks and Regards,
Anjali C. G.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not play with Watir on Linux a lot, but the last time I have tried to drive Firefox with watir-webdriver, it worked just fine: http://zeljkofilipin.com/2010/01/12/watir-on-webdriver/